# Wifi (Killer 1535) issues after linux-header update to 4.4.0-53

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, kernel, suspend

I recognized some "improvements" to my wifi-connection on my Dell XPS 13 9360 DE after the last update of linux-header.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

uname-a

```
Linux debby 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg

```
[  190.122986] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  190.123001] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[  190.123008] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  190.123022] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  190.123033] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  190.123042] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  190.123053] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  190.123066] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  190.123076] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  190.123086] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  190.123096] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[  193.929587] wlp58s0: authenticate with 5c:49:xx:xx:xx:xx
[  193.962989] wlp58s0: send auth to 5c:49:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[  193.964196] wlp58s0: authenticated
[  193.967818] wlp58s0: associate with 5c:49:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[  193.975898] wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from 5c:49:xx:xx:xx:xx (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  193.979704] wlp58s0: associated
[  193.993046] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[  193.993059] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  193.993065] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  193.993071] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[  193.993077] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[  193.993082] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[  193.993090] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[  193.993125] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[  193.993132] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[  193.993139] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  193.993151] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  193.993163] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 200000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  193.993194] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 200000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  193.993203] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm), (0 s)
[  193.993210] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[  194.025239] wlp58s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (23 - 3) dBm as advertised by 5c:49:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

I takes 3 minutes after boot to connect to my wifi, and I could not reconnect to wifi after wakeup from sleep/suspend.

All worked before I updated linux-kernel-headers.

I got this error in dmesg:

```
 14.636058] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   14.636320] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   14.636327] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   16.832396] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[   16.832408] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
```

The firmware-5.bin issue is not relevant, but I do not get those other errros before. Anyone got the same problems or got a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I could get my wifi work better:

1.) I looked at the files in folder `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0` and there were two files, I never saw before. I looked at this folder several times to resolve my BT-problems.

2.) The files `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin.wifi-qca6174` and `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin.wifi-qca6174` are new and I added `.old` to their filename.

3.) It seems those connection-problems are much smaller now. Sometimes I have to wait some seconds, but not 3 minutes.